# how to run jekyll with docker compose getting - Unsupported config option for services: 'site'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jekyll

I looked at: [jekyll guide for installing with docker](https://github.com/jekyll/docker) and I see there:

```
services:
  site:
    command: jekyll serve
    image: jekyll/jekyll:latest
    volumes:
      - $PWD:/srv/jekyll
      - $PWD/vendor/bundle:/usr/local/bundle
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
      - 35729:35729
      - 3000:3000
      -   80:4000
```

and usage:

```
docker-compose run site jekyll new site
```

but when I create a docker-compose.yml with the above yaml and then run the command `docker-compose run site jekyll new site` I get:

```
$ docker-compose run site jekyll new site
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services: 'site'
```

what did i miss from the guide or what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  site:
    command: jekyll serve
    image: jekyll/jekyll:latest
    volumes:
      - $PWD:/srv/jekyll
      - $PWD/vendor/bundle:/usr/local/bundle
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
      - 35729:35729
      - 3000:3000
      - 80:4000
```

Your issue:

You didn't declare a version at the top of your compose file which is mandatory for docker-compose. It should be compatible with the version of docker you are running. You can find more info [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/)

Comment: maybe i'm missing something but i get: $ docker-compose run site jekyll new
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services: 'site'
$ vi docker-compose.yml 
$ cat docker-compose.yml 
services:
  site:
    command: jekyll serve
    image: jekyll/jekyll:latest
    volumes:
      - $PWD:/srv/jekyll
      - $PWD/vendor/bundle:/usr/local/bundle
    command: ["jekyll", "new", "site"]
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
      - 35729:35729
      - 3000...

Comment: $ docker --version
Docker version 17.06.1-ce, build 874a737

$ cat docker-compose.yml 
version '17.06.1-ce'

services:
  site:
    command: jekyll serve
    image: jekyll/jekyll:latest
    volumes:
      - $PWD:/srv/jekyll
      - $PWD/vendor/bundle:/usr/local/bundle
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
      - 35729:35729
      - 3000:3000
      - 80:4000

$ docker-compose run site jekyll new site
ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 3, column 9

Comment: Can you edit your question with that info as its really hard to read

Comment: @Jas Why is your version `'17.06.1-ce' `? It should be a valid version number like what I linked to in my answer.

Comment: Does there need to be a colon there - `version: '3.2'` ?